# How To Parse Invalid JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a data-set and I have requested that it is sent to me in JSON. This data-set however contains a backslash which causes issues when I am trying to parse it. Other then fixing the JSON file, is there anything I can do in JS (ie - escape the slash)?

data.json:

```js
{
    "Name": "Wonderful Buffet",
    "Address": "1234 Main Street \"
}
```

script.js:

```js
$.ajax('data.json').done( function(data) {
    console.log(data); //Outputs nothing
});
```

Comment: Do you know you'll always get this slash in address? If yes, I would write a regex around it and create an integration test with the third party JSON service you are using so you know when they wind up fixing it on their side. Tell jQuery you expect "text" as your datatype. Make the regex look for a single backslash.

Comment: Yes, you can parse it as a string and fix the error before trying to parse it as json. Good luck! (you're going to need it) I think it would be far more productive to ask for the json to be fixed instead.

Comment: There is a good chance that I will receive the slash somewhere in the data. Unfortunately, all of the keys are dynamically so the slash can appear anywhere. Thanks for the tips guys :)

Comment: What you should do is request the provider to output proper JSON. Seriously. You could solve this with f.e. a regexp but just why, your data should be correct.

Comment: Same problem occurs to me once. If you could read this json file through a jstl hidden tag, then I have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape a `\` by replacing it with `\\`. F.e:

```js
var myVar = "one\\slash";
alert (myVar);
```

But this should be done on the provider side, not on the receiving end. People shouldn't be sending you unparseable JSON, that's just bad manners.